# Shorthand for "If greater than, then equal to" in Acttionscript?

Tags: java, c#, actionscript-3, operators, ternary-operator

Is there a shorthand method to write the following code? Often in games we want to make sure certain things dont leave a boundary, or more generally, we want to stop an index of an array from going beyond the bounds of an array. I've always written it this way, but am wondering if there is a shorthand in Actionscript, Java, or C#

In Actionscript:

```
index++;
if (index > array.length - 1) index = array.length - 1;
```

as far as I can tell, there is no operator that accomplishes this, though perhaps I am mistaken. I know the ternary operator is similar `if (condition) ? value if true : value if false`

Comment: Which language are you actually interested in?  If you need to know the answer for Java, C# and ActionScript, then  you should ask three separate questions; otherwise, how will you accept a correct answer, when most people will only give you one of the three?

Comment: They're all relatively the same for what I need. If there is a difference, I can google it. It's not exactly specific to AS3 for me, but that is what I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Math.min` :

```
index = Math.min (index+1, array.length-1);
```

Comment: This is the shortest I've seen and easier to read than ternary operation, though technically not shorthand. Thanks!

Comment: It also works for non-integers and varying increments/decrements

Answer (score 2):

For the generic condition of `if (condition) set variable` (as opposed to your specific case) you could use the following:

```
variable = (condition) ? (set if true) : (set if false)
```

In your case, this turns in to:

```
index = index > array.length - 1 ? index = array.length - 1 : index;
```

It works in Java, Actionscript, and C#.

Comment: wouldnt the `if false` value be `index++`?

Comment: @PremierBromanov It could be either. If you want to increment, then check, then the `index++` should be before the entire statement. If you want to check, then either increment or do the other, then yes, the `index++` should be there in place of `index`.

Comment: Okay. Good to know, however I think `index = Math.min (index+1, array.length-1);` is a bit more concise and readable, though technically yours was shorthand and his was not.

Comment: @PremierBromanov Mine is a more general case. Using `Math.min` is definitely more readable for this specific instance, but it's not what you'd use everywhere.

Comment: True. Though in the case of checking if something is greater than max or less than zero, It's simpler to write `Math.Max(Math.Min(index, array.Length - 1), 0);` as another suggested. That's why you all get +1

Answer (score 1):

If your code looks like this (C#):

```
index++;

if (index > array.length - 1)
    index = array.length - 1;
```

You're doing the equality testing no matter what anyway, so why not do it before the assignment?

```
if (index < array.Length)
    index++;
```

I don't know of any shorter method in C#, but you could write your own extension to use, so you don't have to copy/paste the check throughout your code:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    // Returns the index if it falls within the range of 0 to array.Length -1
    //  Otherwise, returns a minimum value of 0 or max of array.Length - 1
    public static int RangeCheck(this Array array, int index)
    {
        return Math.Max(Math.Min(index, array.Length - 1), 0);
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
var index = yourArray.RangeCheck(index);
```

Comment: That is not pseudocode. That is a text description of what should happen.

Comment: The first shorthand works, assuming we're talking only about integers and single increments. Otherwise no. But, that *is* what I asked, so I'm not holding it against you :)

Comment: Also the RangeCheck is very very handy, but not enough for me to write one since I dont check ranges all that much in this specific code

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, it's also more efficient because you won't make unnecessary increments:

```
if( index < array.length ) index++;
```